# default value corresponding to null key in jackson

Tags: spring, jackson, annotations

Is there any annotation in jackson dependency in spring to all default value to those key who mapped to null value using jackson.

here is sample json example

```js
{
 first-name : null,
 last-name : "somevalue"
}


will mapped to


{
 first-name : "defaultvalue"
 last-name : "somevalue"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no out of the box solution for it. You have multiple ways to tackle this, by using custom serializer or just using an if condition in the getter method.

Something like this:

```
public String getFirstName() {
        if (firstName == null)
            return "defaultvalue";
        return firstName;
}
```

Comment: yes, this is the only way that i have already found till date, but  i  have  approx 100+ key in different beans in whole module.
           Applying the same on all these beans is not efficient way. Please post if any thing new found regarding this.

Comment: May I know what do you mean by efficient way here? In case of change management, it would be similar to having annotation for each property in every class and if you mean performance overhead, I doubt that because any other possible method would also be similar in one way or another.